# JavaScript: Fit part of string into a DOM container, save the overflow

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which is written into a div tag. This div has a limited height and therefore I want the overflow to be put into another variable so that it can be written to a different div later on.

ie.

```
var poststr = "a very very long string which overflows its container";
document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = poststr-*[overflowtext]*;

var overflow = *[overflowtext]*;
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to create new `div`'s ? you can resize your div according to the text so it will be never overflowed

Comment: What `overflow` is supposed to contain ? a string ?

Comment: It's supposed to be a document editor, and the new div represents a new page. [overflow] is a string

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial solution, one that still needs work.  I kept thinking about this problems during a meeting today, and tried to hack it together afterward.  But I don't have time to work through the remaining issues.  There is an **[example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/re827/)**.  Click the "Test" button to see how it splits up the sample text.  You can choose different text blocks (excerpts from speeches by famous American leaders) or enter your own.  You can also choose how many lines of text you want to divide on, but if you choose anything greater than two, you will need to increase the height of the #callout div, which is the first selector in the CSS secion.

The basic idea is to use the DOM node you want to fill out and the the text you want to fill it with to calculate how much will fit, then split the string based on that.  My implementation, though, required another piece of information, which was the number of lines of text to include.  I believe that we should be able to derive that, but couldn't get it quickly enough.

The important code looks like this:

```
var split = function($div, lines, text) {
    var origHeight = $div.height();
    $div.css("height", "auto");
    $div.html(new Array(lines + 1).join("<br/>"));  // would like to remove
    var height = $div.height();         // and calculate this more directly
    var point = 1, newHeight;
    do {
        $div.text(text.substring(0, point));
        newHeight = $div.height();
    } while (newHeight <= height && point++ < text.length);
    $div.height(origHeight);
    point--;
    return [text.substring(0, point), text.substring(point)]    
}
```

This solution uses jQuery, but you can think of it as scaffolding if that offends your sensibilities.  We can remove it easily enough later, but it made a proof of concept easier to create.

This does not deal with the fact that things are split mid-word.  That should be an easy problem to fix.  I thought that the height problem is more interesting so far.  If that can be solved, the word one should be pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how the demo works (I think), but do you have any thoughts on how to get the height of the container and how much data will fit into it, remembering that there could be different font sizes & images? What I need is some way to flow the text into as many divs (pages) as necessary to fit the whole document in.

Comment: @StorySystems: I think if you want full markup and not just text in the DIVs, this solution probably would not be particularly easy to extend.  But if you do, how would you start, as the original post said, with a string?  As to the different font sizes and such, that should just work.  There's nothing in `split` which explicitly uses any DOM characteristics of the DIV except its height.  Of course even that's really faked out by the artificial `lines` parameter.  That's the part I would like to change.

Comment: @StorySystems: And dividing it into multiple "pages" should be a simple matter of applying the same techniques again and again, each time with a new DIV and the remaining (overflowed) text, until the overflow is empty.  That part shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what the max length is for your container. This first step is entirely dependent on your context and you'll need to deal with it yourself or ask a separate SO question about how to determine the max length string a given container could hold.

Then use JavaScript's [`String.prototype.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) as such:

```
// some code to figure out what the max length is before overflow--depends entirely on your context
// we'll set it to a var named `maxlength` then we'll use it like:

var poststr = "a very very long string which overflows its container",
    content = poststr.substr(0, maxlength),
    overflow = poststr.substr(maxlength);


document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = content;
```

Comment: Thanks, will check at next opportunity   :)

Comment: @JAAulde: But unless the OP is using a fixed-width font, max length is not really a meaningful concept.  This can only be done in conjunction with the actual string, and I see no simple way to find where to break except a binary search for the last location which fits...

Comment: @ScottSauyet, agreed--that's why I mentioned what I did about needing code to calculate the `maxlength`, and how it would be very contextually specific. That context being the container, the fonts, etc.

Comment: @JAAulde, I guesss that's a partial answer to the very simplest part of this problem.  :-)  But the hard part remains.

Comment: @ScottSauyet as I read the question and sample code (confusing as it is) I read a request to determine how to remove what is, essentially, a substring. I answered what I believed to have been asked, while giving a caveat that the OP may not have thought through the entirety of the problem. If the OP was not asking what I believed him to have been, it'll come out in the answer-acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the event to create a new page with `Overflowed String` and to get the content of your `notOverflowed String`

**Variables needed:**

```
var maximumLength = 50//limit chars each page. its an example you need to know what is your limit chars.
var maximumHeight = 500//its the maximum page height value, customize it.
var poststr = "a very very long string which overflows its container";
strNotOverflowed     = poststr.substr(0, maximumLength); 
overflowedCharacters = poststr.substr(maximumLength, poststr.length);
```

**Events:**

**Event by max character length:**

```
$('.yourPageClass').keydown(function(this){
  if ($(this).html().length > maximumLength){
    if ($('.newPage') != null){
      $('body').append("<div class=newPage>"+overflowStr+"</div>");
    }
    $('.newPage').focusin();
  }
});
```

**Event by max height:**

```
$('.yourPageClass').keydown(function(this){
  if ($(this).height() > maximumHeight){
    if ($('.newPage') != null){
      $('body').append("<div class=newPage>"+overflowStr+"</div>");
    }
    $('.newPage').focusin();
  }

});
```

Comment: I think this only works if you can deal with fixed string lengths.  If you're trying to fit into containers (as suggested by "overflow"), then it's significantly more complicated.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right.

Comment: @ScottSauyet maybe my new edit solves what you are talking about, take a look

Comment: @PauloRoberto I like the idea of keeping of track of the growing height & reacting when it exceeds max, but I don't really understand your example code...there seems to be a lot missing and some undeclared vars in use. Also, the approach would run into a lot of issues in the context of a document editor and key handling as you couldn't assume the height exceeded max due to text where the carat is currently located. This is because a user can go back to a previous point in the doc and begin inserting text.  There would still be a need to calculate the length of string which caused the overflow.

Comment: @JAAulde Yes, but, im giving a way to do it, i cannot provide a perfect code, i dont have time to do it and the author need to work and learn byself understanding the problems and it will learn it forever after finished. Maybe if i provided a perfect code he was going to paste it and forget it...

Comment: @PauloRoberto: My comment was actually poorly said.  What I said in respose to JAAulde's answer is more what I meant.  You're right that there is a problem with changing text if, as the OP's comments say, this has to do with editable text.  But my main concern was just to be able to do this once with anything other than a monospaced font.

Comment: @PauloRoberto yeah, I hear ya. I didn't mean to be overly critical. I'm just coming off of developing an in-browser text-editing piece of code, so the problems are fresh in my mind. I mostly wanted the OP to understand that he has many considerations to deal with. I +1'ed you for your efforts and thought process. :)

Comment: @JAAulde Sure. Do a text editor in-browser is actually a lot complicated and it will give the programmer thousands of headache because you have to consider millions of possibilities. ^^ and thanks for the recognition.